# How to fire an event when user change a dropdownlist inside an asp.net listview?

Tags: asp.net, listview

i have a Listview that i use like a gridview. inside the itemtemplate i have only a 'modifyble' field, a dropdownlist.

I would like to fire a 'Save' event when user change the dropdownlist. I know i have to set up the autopostback = true of the dropdownlist but i don't know how to fire the event because visual studio don't allow me to create the 'on change event' of the dropdownlist when it is inside a listview.

This is my code example

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvDmr" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsDmr" DataKeyNames="id">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table style="width: 100%;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8">
                <tr style="width: 100%;">
                    <td class="colonna-griglia" style="width: 5%;">
                        <%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("data_rilevazione")).ToString("d") %>
                    </td>
                    <td class="colonna-griglia">
                        <%# Eval("rivista")%>
                    </td>
                    <td class="colonna-griglia">
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="myComboBox" DataSourceID="dsAgenti" DataTextField="customer"
                            DataValueField="customer" Width="150px" AutoPostBack="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
           ...
           ....
    </asp:listview>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not get this in `designer` view, but if you directly add `event` handler it will definitely work. Following are code snippet for this.

1. Add `OnSelectedIndexChanged="myComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged"` to `myComboBox`.

> ```
>  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="myComboBox" DataSourceID="dsAgenti" DataTextField="customer"
>                             DataValueField="customer" Width="150px" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="myComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged">
>                         </asp:DropDownList>
> ```

2. Next in serverside , use following for `event` handler.

> ```
> protected void myComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     DropDownList ddlListFind = (DropDownList)sender;
>     ListViewItem item1 = (ListViewItem)ddlListFind.NamingContainer; // item1, is current row of Listview, which hold the dropdownlist that caused postback. 
> }
> ```

More help - http://forums.asp.net/t/1357900.aspx?SelectedIndexChanged+of+a+DropDownList+which+is+inside+a+ListView

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    ListViewItem dst = (ListViewItem)ddlListFind.NamingContainer;
    DropDownList gddl = (DropDownList)dst.FindControl("dropdownlist1");

    HiddenField hid_msg = (HiddenField)item1.FindControl("hidmsg");
    hid_msg.Visible = true; hid_msg.Value = "Dropowntext : " + gddl.SelectedItem.Text.Trim() + " and value of dropdown is : " + gddl.SelectedItem.Value.Trim();


    }
```

Or visit this link for more detail:
https://forums.asp.net/t/1357900.aspx?SelectedIndexChanged+of+a+DropDownList+which+is+inside+a+ListView